# Can I use both UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert and UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete two button together?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I return `canEditRowAtIndexPath` is `YES`. If I swipe left, I can see the delete button and implement my delete action. How can I do if I swipe left, both insert button and delete button appear together?

I know there is a way, I should have a custom cell with two button on the right and just add a panGesture to recognize the swipe action. But I want to use Apple provide for us to do such easy work. Just can see insert and delete button together when I swipe the cell left? My apology for my poor expression.

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {
        NSLog(@"click insert");//I only have delete button, I also want to have insert button .
    }
    if(editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        NSLog(@"click delete");
   }
}
```

I know tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath can do this job … But it is provide for IOS8.0 and later,,How to do for IOS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least as of iOS 8 this can't be done (I don't know if this changed in iOS 9). A cell can only have one of the 3 possible editing styles - None, Insert, or Delete. `UITableViewCell` does not support both Insert and Delete at the same time. When the table is in editing mode, the cell will show either no button, an insert icon on the left, or the delete icon on the left based on the row's single editing style.

It actually makes no sense to have both insert and delete on the same row. What does that mean for the user? Normally a table view would only have a single row (per section) that might have the insert editing style. This row, when tapped, allows the user to add a new row to the table view. Other existing rows might have the delete editing style to allow the user to delete that specific row.

So again, what would it mean for a single row to have both insert and delete editing styles?

Comment: thank you very much …. I just tell a simple example.. Actually I want to have a more button and delete button when I swipe left ….YES, have both insert and delete do not make sense...

Comment: Having multiple buttons appear when swiping the cell is not standard functionality provided by Apple's APIs. And that is completely different from the built-in editing style. Search github. I believe there are several custom table view cell classes there that implement what you want.